# Inject Services in Grails Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, dependency-injection

I know that you can simply inject a service in unit test method using:

```
defineBeans {
   someService(SomeService)
}
```

But when I need to inject service inside a service (the service `someService` calls itself another service `some2Service`). When I run the test with above code I receive:

```
Message: Cannot invoke method someMethod() on null object
```

Is it possible to inject a service into a service in the unit test?

Thanks. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use spring beans in a unit test you need to do the following:

- Include all the services and other beans the test depends on in the `defineBeans` closure.
- Set the `autowire` property to `true` for beans that need to have other beans injected.

For example:

```
defineBeans {
    someService(SomeService) { bean ->
        bean.autowire = true
    }
    some2Service(Some2Service)
}
```

Comment: is it supported in Grails 2.24 ?

Answer (score 0):

you can set your member variable which is service by using ref

```
MyService(MyProvider) {
        userDetailsService = ref("userDetailsService")
        springSecurityService = ref("springSecurityService")
        userService = ref("userService")
    }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: is it supported in Grails 2.2.4 version ?

Comment: Yes it is... I used this is in version 1.3.6