# Couldn't Inject Service class in grails unit test- Test Fails

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I am executing a simple test, but the test fails because couldn't inject service bean into test class. below is my test class

```
class QuoteServiceTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

      def quoteService
    void testStaticQuote() {
        def staticQuote = quoteService.getStaticQuote()

        assertEquals("Messi", staticQuote.author)
        assertEquals("Watch me today against Man-City", staticQuote.content)
    }
}
```

my test fails with following error

```
 Cannot invoke method getStaticQuote() on null object
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getStaticQuote() on null object
 at qotd.QuoteServiceTests.testStaticQuote(QuoteServiceTests.groovy:9)
```

Comment: Which version of Grails?

Comment: Grails version is 1.3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using a version before 2 (and JUnit instead of Spock), you need to manually add the service:

```
class QuoteServiceTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    def quoteService 

    void setUp() {
        quoteService = new QuoteService()
    }

    void testStaticQuote() {
        def staticQuote = quoteService.getStaticQuote()
        // ...
```

If you are using Grails 2 or later, then you need an annotation:

```
@TestFor(QuoteService) // Allows you to call the QuoteService via 'service'
class QuoteServiceTests {
    void testStaticQuote() {
        def staticQuote = service.getStaticQuote()
        // ...
```

Comment: but this is not Dependency Injection...? I mean for version < 2

Comment: @ProgrammerKhan No, it's not.  Do you need dependency injection?  You can do something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302880/inject-services-in-grails-unit-test, but I prefer the approach above as if you need to modify QuoteService (ie mocking dependent services), it gets reset before every test run. Although I guess I don't know if dependency injection does that too or not.

Comment: Ok thank you @Sneaky, BTW I couldn't understand the example in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302880/inject-services-in-grails-unit-test%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B can you explain it please?

Comment: @ProgrammerKhan As far as I can tell, it just wires the bean to your current context.  I guess it's only for Grails 2+ anyway.  This blog post may help: http://blog.freeside.co/post/41774569512/wiring-taglib-dependencies-in-unit-tests