# Failing to save during Test on Controller

Tags: unit-testing, grails, testing, grails-2.0, spock

I have been struggling with this for quite sometime and it seems like a common problem, with no solution that worked for me.

What I am trying to do is test the controller which calls a save(), and inside the save() the method calls a service to save the employee with the given command objects.

This is how the code looks like:

```
 def save(EmployeeInputCommand employeeCommand, AddressCommand addressCommand) { 
    if (addressCommand.address.validate()) {
        println "Validated address input"
        employeeManagerService.save(employeeCommand, addressCommand)
        println "Employee should be saved"
        println "------------------------->"
        println "${employeeGetterService.each {errors}}"
        flash.message = "Employee has been successfully created!"
        redirect(action: "index")
    } else {
        println "Addrescommand didnt validate: ${addressCommand.errors}"
        flash.message = "Please input valid data!!!"
        redirect(action: "create", model: [employee: employeeCommand, address: addressCommand])
    }
}
```

The service contains this:

```
def save(EmployeeInputCommand employeeCommand, AddressCommand addressCommand) {
    def employee = new Employee(employeeCommand.properties)
    employee.address = addressCommand.address
    for (id in employeeCommand.s) {
        employee.addToSkills(Skill.get(id))
    }
    if (employee.validate()) {
        employee.address.save()
        employee.save()
    }
    else {
       return false
    }
}
```

I know this works when I try to actually save the employee in my application, but during the Unit Test process nothing happens.

My Test:

```
     def "Create an Employee with good params"() {
    given: "A valid employee command object"
    def employeeCommand = new EmployeeInputCommand(
            name: "John",
            surname: "Smith",
            birthdate: Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", "1992-06-08"),
            salary: 21000,
            s: [1, 3, 5]
    )

    and: "Also a valid address command object"
    def addressCommand = new AddressCommand(
            street: "Green Alley",
            houseid: "42",
            city: "Odense",
            county: "Fyn",
            postCode: "5000 C"
    )

    expect:
    addressCommand.validate()
    !Employee.findByNameAndSurname("John", "Smith")

    when: "Saving employee"
    request.method = "POST"
    controller.save(employeeCommand, addressCommand)
    Employee employee = Employee.findByNameAndSurname("John", "Smith")

    println Employee.list()

    then: "The employee is created, and browser redirected"
    Employee.count == 4
    employee
    employee.skills.size() == 3
    employee.address.postCode == "5000 C"
}
```

The test is failing with a null error when the controller.save() is called. I have spend too much time trying to solve this, which has all been in vain

This is the output screenshot

[image: Error output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe testing a controller should cover the service logic. I'd mock the service, if I were to write a unit test for a controller, and test the service separately in its own unit/integration tests.
For example:

```
/*
 * in controller spec
 */
def setup() {
  def serviceMock = new MockFor(EmployeeManagerService)
  serviceMock.ignore('save') { ec, ac ->
    Employee.buildWithoutSave().save(validate: false)
  }
  serviceMock.use {
    controller.employeeManagerService = new EmployeeManagerService()
  }
}

def 'testFoo'() {
  when:
  // ...
  controller.employeeManagerService.save()
  // ...
  then:
  // ...
}
```

Note that the code is using the excellent [Build Test Data plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/build-test-data).

Comment: Yes thats right, and I am not trying to test a service in the controller. The aim is to test weather the controller can call mocked service which saves the Employee. But the issue lies in getting to mock the service properly to do this test, and future tests which will require mocked services

Comment: I see. I've updated the code so that you get an idea of how to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with service in unit testing. In unit testing, you need `defineBeans` closure to use spring beans-

```
void "test the filter"() {
    setup:
    defineBeans {
        employeeManagerService(EmployeeManagerService) { bean ->
            bean.autowire = true
        }
    }

    when:
    ...

    then:
    ...
}
```

Ref# [Inject Services in Grails Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302880/inject-services-in-grails-unit-test)

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform your tests as Integration Tests, not Unit Tests. Integration testing is needed when you're testing database-related logic (CRUD ops), not just mocking the CRUD ops which is what unit tests do.